# jqgrid php query explanation

Tags: jqgrid-php

I'm trying out jqgrid and I can't figure out this query, specifically what a, b, client and client_id are?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_name a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id");
```

I'm trying to adapt the code from one of the demos of the site and this doesn't seem to be explained anywhere.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `FROM table_name a, clients b` is pulling records from the tables `table_name` *and* `clients`.

When you see `a` later in the query, it's referring to the table named `table_name` and `b` is referring to the table `clients`.

Comment: ahh, I see. I think I was being thrown off be the fact there is no mention of a second table named clients in the example. Thanks, that makes sense.